# Define a function with the condition that it must be positive

Tags: function-construction, variable-definitions

I have a function `f(x)` and I want to define a new function `g(x)` that is equal to `f(x)` only when `f(x)` is positive.

What is the right way to do that?

Sorry for this silly question, but I cannot find the proper way to accomplish this simple task in *Mathematica*.

Comment: Maybe `g[x_]:=Max[f[x],0]` ? (Provided I correctly remember the syntax of Max). But what should be the value of your new function when f is not positive? Is the zero value important?

Comment: @Peltio That sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: @Peltio it's reasonable, but I'd like that the function `g(x)` was undefined when `f(x)` was negative.

Comment: Try [Piecewise function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Piecewise.html), if it's works for you.

Comment: @s.s.o In this way `g(x)` is defined only for positive `x`, instead I want that it is defined only when `f(x)` is positive.

Comment: @ Fabrizio Yes, I noticed that a bit late see the below answer with using Condition.

Comment: @s.s.o yes, that's perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the Mathematica documentation about Condition /;

here is a simple example :

```
f[x_] := x + 5;
g[x_] := f[x] /; f[x] > 0

g[5]
```

> 10

```
g[-9]
```

> g[-9]

Comment: @Szabolcs, in fact it was what I suggested as comment but it was not what OP asked for.